# oneToMany bidirectional don't work

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have two classes, and want to make bidirectional manyToOne relationship. I got parent class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SECTIONS")
public class Section_beta implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "SECTION_ID")
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

private List<Question_beta> questions = new LinkedList<>();


@OneToMany(mappedBy = "section", cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    @OrderColumn(name = "SECTION_QUESTION_ORDER")
    public List<Question_beta> getQuestions() {
        return questions;
    }

    public void setQuestions(List<Question_beta> questions) {
        this.questions = questions;
    }
```

And child class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "QUESTIONS")
public class Question_beta implements Serializable, Cloneable {


@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "QUESTION_ID")
public Long getQuestionID() {
    return questionID;
}
    private Section_beta section;
    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    @JoinColumn(name = "SECTION_ID", referencedColumnName = "SECTION_ID")
    public Section_beta getSection() {
        return section;
    }

    public void setSection(Section_beta section) {
        this.section = section;
    }
```

The problem is that hibernate crushes with message:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: Question_beta.SECTION_ID in Section_beta.questions.
```

I have no clue what's wrong, anyone?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = {...})
@JoinColumn(name = "SECTION_ID")
public Section_beta getSection() {
    return section;
}
```

The "name" field in the `@JoinColumn` has to be the id field in your Section_beta class, not in your table.

Comment: I tried your advice, but got 
`"Caused by:com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'id' in 'field list'"`. As I read in JPA documentation name must be name of field in sql table.

Comment: Could you add your id attributes to your classes in your post?

Comment: Done - I added requested parameters

Comment: I think I got this - I forgot to tell that I'm rewriting application, but on alod dataTables - that's why, some fields in database got `null` as a `SECTION_ID`, so I added to my code:
`@ManyToOne(optional = true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)`
and now it looks like it's working correctly. well - at least it deploys:)

Comment: It's nice to hear this!

Comment: After testing it looks like the problem is solved. New data saves correctly and problem was with old data that had null values in new columns.